# Make each section under nested forEach loop collapsible using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, jquery-ui

I am super new to JQuery, literally started yesterday, and I need help.

I've a Map    < String, List < Object>> dataMap and i want to make all the entries in the Map collapsible and also each list within each map entry to be collapsible as well. I am creating buttons for all those entries and their ID's will be assigned at runtime based on the values retrieved from the map. I am not sure how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<a:section id="${'my-section-id'}">
    <a:heading>My Sample Page</a:heading>
    <c:forEach items="${dataMap}" var="map" varStatus="mainIndex">
        <!-- Make below section collapsible on click -->
        <a:button><c:out value="${map.key}" /></a:button>
            <c:forEach items="${map.value}" var="object" varStatus="childIndex">
                <!-- Make below section collapsible on click -->
                <a:button><c:out value="${object.key}" /> 
                </a:button>
                <!—Display rest of the content here -->
            </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
</a:section>
```

I can assign unique section/button ID's by doing something like this - "mainSection+mainIndex" and "childSection+childIndex" but not sure how to write a on click function for that.

Note: It doesn't necessarily have to be buttons. It could be any component with a label

Answer (score 0):

Following thing works but not sure if it's the best way to do it

```
<a:section id="${'my-section-id'}">
    <a:heading>My Sample Page</a:heading>
    <div id="collapsible">
        <c:forEach items="${dataMap}" var="map" varStatus="mapStatus">
            <!-- Make below section collapsible on click -->
            <a:button data-showhideid="collapse_${mapStatus.index}">><c:out value="${map.key}" /></a:button>
            <div id="collapse_${mapStatus.index}">
                <c:forEach items="${map.value}" var="object" varStatus="valueStatus">
                    <a:button data-showhideid="collapse_${mapStatus.index}_${valueStatus.index}">
                    <div id="collapse_${mapStatus.index}_${valueStatus.index}">
                        <!-- Make below section collapsible on click -->
                        <a:button><c:out value="${object.key}" /> 
                        </a:button>
                        <!—Display rest of the content here -->
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</a:section>
```

And then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#collapsible').on('click', '[data-showhideid]', function(){
            $('#' + $(this).attr('data-showhideid')).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```